# Pass dictionary to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app and am looking to pass a dictionary from the POST method to another module in a subdirectory.
My main.py looks like this

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from app.api import mymodule
from app.api.mymodule import MyClass


app = FastAPI(debug = True, version="0.0.1")


class MyAPIModel(BaseModel):
    """
    Required input from frontend for IP Allocation
    """
    forename: str
    surname: str
    age: int

@app.get("/")
async def default():
    return {"Default root page"}


@app.get("/home")
async def home():
    return {"message": "Homepage for Application"}


@app.post("/ip")
async def ip(request: MyAPIModel):
    superhero = request.dict()
    superhero_request = MyClass.get_type(superhero)
```

Mymodule.py looks like

```
import api

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, superhero):
        self.mysetup = api(url, token)
        self.superhero_info = superhero

    """
    Here is where I want to access the dictionary
    and use it
    """

    def get_type(self):
        return self.superhero_info
```

My POST request is a json dict of the BaseModel

```
{
    "forename": "peter", 
    "surname": "parker",
    "age": 28
}
```

But doing so I get the following error

```
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 550, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 148, in app
    dependant=dependant, values=values, is_coroutine=is_coroutine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 101, in run_endpoint_function
return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "./app/main.py", line 36, in ip
Allocate.get_type(iprequest)
  File "./app/api/mymodule.py", line 21, in get_type
return self.superhero_info
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'superhero'
```

Is there a way to pass the dictionary to the method class so I can perform other tasks on it before returning?

Comment: It looks to me you're calling the static function, but the `get_type()` is not static. You need to instantiate the MyClass object first, then call `get_type()`. Like this, `MyClass().get_type(myrequest)`

Comment: I think you forgot the line with the name of the error in your traceback

Comment: Added the full error @Donatien

Comment: Using MyClass().get_type(myrequest) returns null @ThuYeinTun

Comment: But does it cause the error again? Returning null is most likely because your request doesn't have `forename`.

Comment: No error now, just returns null. I've changed return myrequest.get("forename") to return myrequestparams and still seeing null.

Comment: You didn't add the error. You posted part of the traceback but not the actual error message and exception type (the last line)

Comment: I think maybe this post is missing some context, because it's not clear what `MyClass` is supposed to do, or what namespace the `myrequest` variable it uses came from or how the rest of your code is structured. As the first commenter pointed out, `MyClass.get_type` is an instance method, so you need to call it either on an instance of the class, or turn it into a `staticmethod` or a `classmethod` but I couldn't tell you which approach makes sense or if it even makes sense to use a class at all without more context about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Iguananaut apologies, Postman doesn't output the error but the docker logs do. Updated. I'm trying to pass the dictionary initalised in main.py to MyClass so it can be used in a few other functions that are querying separate APIs before being returned. Hope I've been clearer now.

Comment: Yes, a little clearer. My original point still stands: you are passing the `MyAPIModel` argument as the `self` argument in `MyClass.get_type` which is an instance method. Actually it should crash here with a `TypeError` instead since you didn't pass enough arguments to `MyClass.get_type` so I'm not sure we're seeing your actual code. But the point is you need to use an *instance* of `MyClass`.

Comment: In other words, somewhere in your code (it's not clear to me where) you need something like `my_thing = MyClass(superhero)` (you need to *instantiate* `MyClass` with whatever `superhero` is).  Then call `my_thing.get_type(myrequestparams)`.

Answer (score 0):

Was pointed in the right direction by the comments. Full working code is

```
@app.post("/ip")
async def ip(request: MyAPIModel):
    mydata = request.dict()
    test = MyClass()
    results = test.get_type(mydata)
    return results
```

Needed to return both in the subclass and the main.py

Comment: That's what I thought. It is a simple error of not instantiating the MyClass, if not obscured by fastapi. And the part about getting the data from request can easily be gleaned from the ofifical documentation of fastapi, which I've never used before. You just need `return MyClass().get_type(request.dict())`. My comment solves your issue of passing the dict to the other module, where to get the dict is another matter entirely.